# "Wait Operation Timed Out" When Reading Records

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

I have some code that reads results into a List from a SqlDataReader, parsing them into domain objects as it goes using reader.GetXXX(int ordinal) methods inside a while reader.Read() loop.

This code generally works fine over very large datasets and across a wide range of queries and tables, but one query hangs midway through reading this list of results and eventually times out with a "Wait Operation Timed Out" error.

I've repeated this a lot of times, and it always hangs on the same record (roughly 336k records into a 337k record set).

If I pause execution while it's hanging i can see that it is midway through parsing a record, and it is hanging on a reader.GetXXX call.

I have tried the following:

- executing the proc manually in ssms (works fine)
- Chunking the calls to the database such that it reads 250k records in a chunk and then requeries to get the rest (it still hung on the same record, but now the record was in the second batch)
- Checking the ID for each record before parsing, and skipping the one that it hangs on (the record after that is parsed but it hangs on the next record).
- Updating stats (parsing gets about 3000 records further before hanging after this)

I'm tempted to blame the database, but given the query runs without a hitch in SSMS, I'm not convinced. Any help much appreciated!

other stuff that may help:

- the proc takes a table valued parameter and joins onto that along with another database table to get its results
- this was originally spotted on a VM running a long way from the client machine, but i have subsequently reproduced it by restoring and connecting to a machine that is under my desk.

edit: as requested, the query is:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE [trading].[Trade_SelectLegalEntityPositionChunked]
        @PartyPositions trading.PartyPositionType READONLY,
        @Offset INT,
        @ChunkSize INT
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @OffsetLocal INT = @Offset;
DECLARE @ChunkSizeLocal INT = @ChunkSize;

SELECT  /* stuff */
FROM    [trading].[Trade]
JOIN    [refdata].[Book] ON [refdata].[Book].[BookId] = [trading].[Trade].[BookId]
JOIN    @PartyPositions pos 
        ON pos.[PartyId] = [refdata].[Book].[LegalEntityId] 
        AND [trading].[Trade].[TradeType] = pos.[TradeType] 
        AND [trading].[Trade].[InstrumentId] = pos.[InstrumentId]
ORDER BY    [trading].[Trade].[TradeId]
OFFSET      @OffsetLocal ROWS FETCH NEXT @ChunkSizeLocal ROWS ONLY;;

END
```

edit: i've also checked:

- other threads - there are none that should be getting in the way: the only threads that are running are the one running the query and the usual supporting threads such as the main thread and message loop (I'm testing from a CUI)

edit (bored yet?)

if i reduce the scope of the query a bit i can see it blocking while parsing a record for about 4 mins. It then carries on reading stuff until it hangs again.

I still cannot see anything much going on in the client - i now have the GcNotification class from CLR via C# running and there isn't any GC going on.This points to the database, as @Crowcoder says but the fact it runs fine in SSMS and it pausing midway through reading a record means I am loathe to blame it. This is probably down to my lack of knowledge about databases though!

Comment: Hi Chris, could you post your source code? Maybe there is something wrong with your query.

Comment: I assume if you craft the `WHERE` clause to return only that offending row it will still time out? Do this in SSMS and view the execution plan for clues.

Comment: @Crowcoder - good point - it works fine when i make that change and i can see the offending row being parsed.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer query added to main question (hopefully this is OK!)